# How to remove specific images / cameras from colmap 3D Poincloud | Clean Colmap

Tags: binary, bin, colmap

How can i remove already registered images/ cameras from colmap 3D Pointcloud. When i run Colmap to reconstruct a 3D Scene i get the following folder output: `database.db, sparse >> 0 >> cameras.bin, images.bin and points3D.bin`. I tied to remove a incorrectly registered camera by deleting it inside colmap and then exporting the Model, this doesnt work. I also tried to remove the images index inside the database.db file which didnt worked. I Think the camera/image data is sotred inside the images.bin file. How can i remove specific camera views inside this file?